# pyModBus : check if coil is True or False

Tags: pymodbus3, pymodbus

I am trying to learn how to introduce values to a PLC trough python ModBus module what I'm currently trying to do is just to read the value of coil 1 to check if its **True** or **false**  so I am using

```
order_ready = client.read_coils(0, 1)
print(order_ready)
```

and I get this as response **ReadBitResponse(8)** how can I get a "**True**" value from reading a coil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the individual coils from the response `ReadCoilResponse` using the `bits` property . More on response could be found [here](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/library/pymodbus.html#pymodbus.bit_read_message.ReadCoilsResponse)

```
order_ready = client.read_coils(0, 1)
if not order_ready.isError():
     #response.bits would return a list (multiple of 8) of booleans each bit representing the output of one coils
    # In your case accessing 1st element should give the actual value
    order_ready = order_ready.bits[0]
else:
     # Handle error
```